# If return value is scalar, push as one row; if iterable, push as multiple rows

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using this piece of code to generate the array. It's a while loop wherein `$povezani` I get an array of connected SKU, and that array should be merged with array $transfer_items but in a way that I have displayed at the bottom. In this way, I have it now I don't get the result I need. Can you help me how to get the desired array?

```
$transfer_items= array();
//Get calculation items in array
if($stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT article_no, mpc, vpc FROM dpb.calculation_items WHERE calculation_id = ? AND used_for_purchase = 1")) {
   $stmt -> bind_param("i", $calculation_id);
   $stmt -> execute();
   $stmt -> store_result();
   $stmt -> bind_result($article_no, $mpc, $vpc);
   while($stmt -> fetch()) {
        $povezani = zamjena_broja($article_no);

        $transfer_items[] = array('article_no' => $povezani,
                                  'mpc' => $mpc,
                                  'vpc' => $vpc);
   }
   $stmt -> close();
}
```

This is the result I get:

```
    array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'article_no' => string '967 65 02-16' (length=12)
      'mpc' => string '33000.00' (length=8)
      'vpc' => string '26400.00' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'article_no' => string '967 66 57-02' (length=12)
      'mpc' => string '35600.00' (length=8)
      'vpc' => string '28480.00' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'article_no' => string '967 32 96-01' (length=12)
      'mpc' => string '7000.00' (length=7)
      'vpc' => string '5600.00' (length=7)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'article_no' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '952 71 57-52' (length=12)
          1 => string '952 71 57-58' (length=12)
      'mpc' => string '1950.00' (length=7)
      'vpc' => string '1560.00' (length=7)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'article_no' => string '966 62 89-01' (length=12)
      'mpc' => string '5500.00' (length=7)
      'vpc' => string '4400.00' (length=7)
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'article_no' => string '967 32 96-01' (length=12)
      'mpc' => string '7000.00' (length=7)
      'vpc' => string '5600.00' (length=7)
```

The result that is giving me a problem is on array 3, and it should look like this:

```
    3 => 
        array (size=3)
          'article_no' => string '952 71 57-52' (length=12)              
          'mpc' => string '1950.00' (length=7)
          'vpc' => string '1560.00' (length=7)
   4 =>
       array (size=3)
          'article_no' => string '952 71 57-58' (length=12)
          'mpc' => string '1950.00' (length=7)
          'vpc' => string '1560.00' (length=7)
```

How can I extract subarray from the array on position 3 and get the desired result I have shown above?

Function zamjena_broja

```
function zamjena_broja($kataloski_broj){

    global $conn;
    include("db_conn.php");

    $kataloski_broj_data = array();

    //Traženje zamjenskog broja
    $upit_zamjena = "SELECT pocetni_broj, zamjenski_broj, glavni_broj
                     FROM dpb.nav_replacement_numbers
                     WHERE glavni_broj = '$kataloski_broj'
                     OR pocetni_broj = '$kataloski_broj'";
    $rezultat_zamjena = mysqli_query($conn, $upit_zamjena) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
    $broj = mysqli_num_rows($rezultat_zamjena);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat_zamjena)){
        $kataloski_broj_data[] = $row["zamjenski_broj"];
        $kataloski_broj_data[] = $row["pocetni_broj"];

    }

    if ($broj > 0) {  
        $kataloski_broj = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $kataloski_broj_data)));
        //var_dump($kataloski_broj);
    } else {
        $kataloski_broj;
    }      
    return $kataloski_broj;

}
```

Comment: Please show us the function `zamjena_broja`

Comment: Not use translite name function

Comment: And a bit more of this code. Specifically how you are binding values from the fetch to variables

Comment: OK, can you give me an idea how to change the concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the function `zamjena_broja` can return an array then you need to process that array within your while loop.

```
while($stmt -> fetch()) {
    $povezani = zamjena_broja($article_no);

    if ( is_array($povezani) ) {
        foreach ($povezani as $one) {
            $transfer_items[] = array('article_no' => $one,
                                      'mpc' => $mpc,
                                      'vpc' => $vpc);
        }
    } else {
        $transfer_items[] = array('article_no' => $one,
                                  'mpc' => $mpc,
                                  'vpc' => $vpc); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could explicitly cast `$povezani` as an array and unconditionally loop.  `$povezani = (array) zamjena_broja($article_no);`

Answer (score 0):

According to above answer, you can try to use `array_map` to achieve it:

```
$merge_arr = ['mpc' => $mpc, 'vpc' => $vpc];
array_map(function($val) use (&$transfer_items, $merge_arr) {
    $transfer_items[] = array_merge(['article_no' => $val] ,$merge_arr);
}, is_array($povezani) ? $povezani : [$povezani]);
```